# Why apex method doesnt work on visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom, method

I am a beginner in the salesforce world. 
I have my **page**:

```
<apex:page controller="opportunityList2Con">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!employees}" var="o">
            <apex:column value="{!o.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!o.Email__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!AnnualSalary}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

I have my **Apex** **class** called *opportunityList2Con* and there I have a **method** called *getAnnualSalary* which looks like that:

```
  Integer getAnnualSalary(Employee__c emp){

    return 123;
}
```

Unfortunately **no such column like annual salary is printed on the screen.**
What do I wrong?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Do you have a space between annual and salary , can you paste your complete class

Comment: There is no mechanism in Visualforce to pass arguments to methods. You could invoke the getter if its signature was `Integer getAnnualSalary()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things...

1. your method must be public
2. methods called from VF cannot have parameters
3. methods called from VF can only return PageReferences (other than
   get methods, which are really just treated as properties)

Visualforce uses a MVC framework. What you really need to do is to create a model to communicate between your View (VF page) and Controller (Apex Class).

In your Controller, create an inner class:

```
public class MyController{
    public List<Employee> employees {get; set;}

    public MyController(){
        employees = new List<Employee>();
        // add employees
    }

    //inner employee class
    public class Employee{
      public MyObject__c obj {get; set;}
      public Employee(MyObject__c obj){
         this.obj = obj;
      }

      public Integer getAnnualSalary(){
          return 123;
      }  
    }
}
```

In your apex page you can treat the AnnualSalary as a property:

```
<apex:page controller="opportunityList2Con">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!employees}" var="o">
            <apex:column value="{!o.obj.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!o.obj.Email__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!o.AnnualSalary}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```